# When to use require vs ActiveSupport::Concern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I wrote a sudoku solver program in Ruby that I want to place inside a Rails 4 app. The file structure for the program at the moment is as follows.

```
- sudoku_solver.rb 
 - board.rb
   - cell.rb
   - column.rb
   - row.rb
   - block.rb
```

Each hierarchy is linked together with `require_relative`.

Now in Rails, I've created `model/sudoku.rb`, which is intended to be `sudoku_solver.rb`. I've read about mixins, concerns, and I don't know how to choose the correct one to use over simply requiring `model/sudoku/board.rb`, `model/sudoku/cell.rb`, etc.

Any guidance would be appreciated. Here's the [repo](https://github.com/kamok/sudoku-solver) for the Ruby program is one wants to see it.

Comment: This link will lead you to an interesting discussion about mixins vs. concerns: http://engineering.appfolio.com/appfolio-engineering/2013/06/17/ruby-mixins-activesupportconcern.   Additionally, I'd point out that requiring a file doesn't have any impact on the design of your code necessarily. You can be including anything, including a mixin or a concern.

Comment: @jaydel Is it a bad choice to just load all the classes when Rails initializes? I'm thinking that it's like stylesheets and should only load when that part of your app needs it.

Comment: Rails already has a `auto_load_paths` in config/application.rb that will make sure you have those things in scope and don't need to require them explicitly. You can add paths to that if you create new directories you want loaded. But that's just for getting access to the code. how you design the code is really an issue of deciding about model vs. concern vs. module for your code.

Comment: @jaydel Oh ok I get it. Thanks.